# Dash datatable width parameter does not work for style_header

Tags: python, datatable, header, plotly-dash

Since I use dash, I have some annoying problems with the style_header parameter of the dash_table.Datatable component.

Indeed, some of them like the colors / background colors work while others like width do not work. It seems that it is linked to the other variable 'fixed_rows' which, when set to true (to make the dashboard header fixed), blocks the width selection.

I've tried with all the versions of dash (from 1.20.0 to the very last one when I write these lines, 2.5.1) and always have this problem.

See below :

- With fixed_rows={'headers': True} :
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqAto.png)
- With fixed_rows not activated :
  [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4MAx.png)

My code :

```
from dash import Dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from tools.visual import colors


cols = ['ColumnA', 'ColumnB', 'ColumnC']

app = Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP], suppress_callback_exceptions=True)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # Dashboard
    html.Div(id="table", children=[
        dash_table.DataTable(
            columns=[{"id": i, "name": i} for i in cols],
            style_header={
                'backgroundColor': colors['bg_board'],
                'color': colors['text_category'],
                'fontWeight': 'bold',
                'textAlign': 'center'
            },
            style_cell={
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                'height': 'auto',
                'width': '200px'
            },
            style_cell_conditional=
            [
                {
                    'if': {'column_id': 'Maturity'},
                    'backgroundColor': colors['bg_board'],
                    'color': colors['text_category'],
                }
            ],
            style_table={
                'overflow': 'auto',
            },
            fill_width=False,
            # fixed_rows={'headers': True},
            css=[{"selector": ".show-hide", "rule": "display: none"}],
            id='tbl'
        )
    ]),
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False, host='0.0.0.0', port=5026)
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably solved your issue but here is my take on it for future reference.

style_cell works for headers and data, style_data works for data cells, style_header works for data.

For a fixed size to work, you need to use the 3 parameters as following:

```
            style_cell={
                # all three widths are needed
                'minWidth': '75px', 'width': '75px', 'maxWidth': '75px',
            },
        )
```